# IOException while overwriting parquet

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have parquet file let's say file name abc/A.parquet and few records are filtered out based on certain condition and create DF and I am trying overwrite file with resulted filtered DF with saveMode overwrite option, but throwing below exception:

command used to overwrite
filterDF.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").parquet("file:/home/psub2/cls_parquet2/file:/home/psub7/abc/A.parquet")

failed while writing rows.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:381)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/psub7/abc/A.parquet does not exist
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.

Pls help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually you can't read and write dataframe from same file. IOException thrown when you try to read df from file A and try write same df into the same file A. You can overwrite A parquet file only if you didn't read dataframe from file A. 
For example you can read dataframe from file A and overwrite file B.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much for your response. I have one query when we write DF to file  name would be randomly taken..How to name destination file specifically B in this case. could you pls help.

Comment: maybe you can just add some suffix to A dir name. For example if you read data from '/some/path/to/dirwithdata' you can write it to '/some/path/to/dirwithdata_changed'

Comment: Thanks a lot Boris Azanov ..I will check it out

Comment: you can write and overwrite the same file if you use checkpointing